# AspNet (DotNet 5) - send JSON data via Websocket in a performant manner

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, websocket, system.text.json

I want to Serialize Objects to JSON and send them via AspNet5 Core Websocket.

What is the most performant way to do this?

There is the Utf8JsonWriter which can write to a Stream directly, but from AspNet I only get the Websocket class, which has the SendAsync function.

Is there no way to send the data, without creating a temporary Memorystream?

Comment: Why not using  `string jsonString = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(modeldata);` to serialize object?

Comment: Because I do not want to allocate a UTF16 string wich then needs to be converted to UTF8 bytes only to be thrown away after.

Comment: So i'd like to serialize to the websocket directly